# Format colon for java string sent in E-mail

Tags: java, string, formatting

i want to format the colons in the below string. After printing the below string, the colons are misplaced.

```
static final String BODY    =  "Message : "+ message
            +"\r\n"+"Contact                : "+Name 
            +"\r\n"+"Contact Phone          : "+Mobile
            +"\r\n"+"Contact Email          : "+Email 
            +"\r\n"+"Home Location          : "+Address 
            +"\r\n\n"+VPROVIDOR ;
```

Actual Output -

Contact              : Mahesh
Contact Phone           : +919999999999
Contact Email          : support@support.com
Home Location          : Parathe wali gali

Expected Output -

[image]

Comment: Could you add your actual result and the expected one?

Comment: @MincongHuang added

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.format`:

```
String.format("%30s:\r\n%30s:\r\n%30s:\r\n%30s:\r\n%30s:\r\n", message, name, mobile, email, address);
```

You can change the alignment by using a pattern like `%-30s`.

More information on the options you can find the javadoc.